# Graphic tool in LaTeX?

Tags: graphics, texstudio

I have started to use TexStudio for making my documents in LaTeX (beginner mode, by the way); and I was wondering if there is any software that allows to make graphs so they can be transformed directly to LaTeX. I mean not necessary plots, but like a sort of Paint so that I can export the graphs to LaTeX, if they are TexStudio plugins would be great.

Comment: I think inkscape is that way.  I have never used so I am just making a guess.

Comment: I don't think there are any plugins for any normal editor. I'd suggest learning to do simple drawings in `tikz`, it is well worth learning

Comment: For Inkscape there is [`inkscape2tikz`](http://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/). There are some other tools that can generate TikZ code, see http://www.texample.net/tikz/resources/

Comment: If you drawings are geometric shapes, you could also check out GeoGebra.  This will give you `TikZ` code to put in your `LaTeX` document.

Answer (score 2):

I guess there is not a single answer to your question. It probably depends on what people are used to use. Personally, I think **Inkscape** [(link)](http://inkscape.org/download/?lang=en) is the way to go, since it is Open Source and works on any Operating System, but any other *vector graphics* editor like **Adobe Illustrator** works as well.

With **Inkscape**  you can export your drawings directly in `pdf` format, cropped to the size of the drawing and chose to omit the text in the `pdf` and create a `LaTeX` file that you can compile separately to add text, change size, include formulas, and so on. The output is also a `pdf` that you simply include as a graphic: `\includegraphics[scale=1]{MyPath/MyFigure}`.

Otherwise, you can have a look at the `overpic` package, which I find extremely useful to add text on top of a figure.

Answer (score 1):

[IPE](http://ipe7.sourceforge.net/) has excellent TeX integration.  It provides many of the standard drawing tools, and all text is rendered through TeX.